# @font-face not working on ff, chrome, and safari (on mac)

Tags: html, css, font-face

I can't get @font-face working in any browser on macs.  I believe this is the relevant code but I will be happy to paste other pieces.  Do macs handle this differently?

```
@font-face {
font-family: BebasNeue;
src: url('fonts/BebasNeue.otf');
}

/*----HEADING----*/
.heading {
font-family: BebasNeue, sans-serif;
}

.word1{
font-size: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
}

.word2{
font-size: 79px;
color: 6a6964;
position: absolute;
top: 54px;
left: 165px;
}

.word3{
font-size: 106px;
position: absolute;
top: 104px;
}

.tagline {
font-family: BebasNeue, sans-serif;
font-size: 35px;
color: c1bcb6;
position: absolute;
top: 205px;
left: 13px;
}

.tagWord2{
color: 6a6964;
}

.copyright {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
color: 6a6964;
font-size: 13px;
font-variant: small-caps;
position: absolute;
top: 245px;
left: 215px;
}
```

PS I had shoulder surgery recently, so I appreciate you patience while i tap at the keyboard with 1 hand.  Thanks!

***So I figured out my error, there was a mistake in the font location and my local machine has the font loaded already.  I don' have enough reputation to answer or delete my own question, so first person to post that as an answer I will mark correct.

Comment: Open up a debugger (firebug etc.), check the NET tab and see of you get a 404 for the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get the BebasNeue.otf font file from?  Could it be that it is not really an otf font?

To make font-face completely cross browser compatible, you need to provide a few more font sources in different formats.  Here is a good starting point: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

Comment: I got it from dafont, it works in ie and chrome in windows...ill read up now on that link

Comment: what if that is the only file?